# Creating spatial index in standalone script as part of output vector layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, spatial-index, standalone, attributeerror

I am making a buffer analysis in a standalone script.

Is it possible to automatically, during the analysis, add index to the output vector layer (".qix" file)?

I tried to add after the analysis like in QGIS2:

```
layer_out = QgsVectorLayer(out, out[-7:-4],'ogr')
```

`layer_out.dataProvider().createSpatialIndex()`

where out is a path to shapefile, out[-7:-4] the shapefile name.
However in QGIS 3.2 Bonn, I got the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'createSpatialIndex'
```

If an automated way of creating index during analysis is not possible, how to create it after it in standalone script?

Comment: The defaul format in QGIS 3 is GeoPackage. Maybe that has some effect. Or does your code still create a shapefile with QGIS 3.2 if you do not try to create the spatial index?

Comment: Without creating an index I have the proper shapefile from the buffer analisys.

Comment: If you just need to have .qix index you can create it with shptree utility. It is originally made for Mapserver https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/ShpTree but it is often delivered together with GDAL. But of course it should still be possible to create it with Python.

Comment: I have just used a version of your code in QGIS LTR 3.22.4 and it worked successfully for me on a Shapefile, the only difference was that I assigned the dataProvider to a new variable and called createSpatialIndex on that.

Comment: @bugmenot123 What is your purpose of starting the bounty? Because `layer_out.dataProvider().createSpatialIndex()` works without an error and makes `.qix` file in a standalone script (QGIS 3.28).

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz oh just random interest with no time to research myself. I searched for something similar and ended up here with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you use `layer_out.dataProvider().createSpatialIndex()` you don't get that error. To get the error you must use `layer_out.createSpatialIndex()`. The code in the question doesn't throw the error: `AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'createSpatialIndex'`

`layer_out.dataProvider().createSpatialIndex()` works without an error and makes `.qix` file in a standalone script (QGIS 3.28).

```
import os
import sys
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.28.1/apps/qgis/python/plugins')
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX_PATH'], True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()
Processing.initialize()
qgs.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

input_file = 'c:/path/to/input.shp'
out_file = 'c:/path/to/out.shp'

out = processing.run("native:buffer",
                     {'INPUT': input_file,
                      'OUTPUT': out_file})["OUTPUT"]

layer_out = QgsVectorLayer(out, out[-7:-4], 'ogr')

# this line generates .qix file
layer_out.dataProvider().createSpatialIndex()

qgs.exec_()
qgs.exitQgis()
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a spatial index in v3 try either:

```
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
```

or

```
index = QgsSpatialIndex(layer.getFeatures())
```

[Using Spatial Index](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#using-spatial-index)

Comment: The question is asking how to create a file based spatial index, not an in-memory one. If an instance of QgsSpatialIndex can be written out as a .qix file then please expand your answer to cover that.